# Visualizing larger weights with thinner lines

Tags: r, visualization, data-visualization, igraph, vertices

I try to visualize data on cultural distances between countries with the use of networks in R. The distances are stored in matrices, e.g.:

```
          AT      BE     CH     CZ
AT    0       0.00276 0.148  0.109
BE    0.00276 0       0.145  0.112
CH    0.148   0.145   0      0.257
CZ    0.109   0.112   0.257  0
```

With the use of `igraph` package I get an image like:

[image: map with cultural distance network]

The code I use:

```
library(maps)
library(igraph)

df<-data.frame(from = c("at", "be", "ch", "cz"), to= c("be", "ch", "cz", "at"),
weight=c(0.003,0.145,0.257,0.109))
meta <- data.frame("name"=c("at", "be", "ch", "cz"),
"lon"=c(14.55,4.46,8.227,14.4738), "lat"=c(47.51,50.5,46.818,50.0755))

g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed=F, vertices=meta)
E(g)$color <- "brown"
# since weights are small, multiplying by 10
E(g)$width <- E(g)$weight*10
lo <- as.matrix(meta[,2:3])
map("world",  xlim = c(-8, 30),
ylim = c(35, 55), asp=1)
plot(g, layout=lo, add = TRUE, rescale = FALSE)
```

Now, the problem is that I want lines to be thin, if the corresponding weight is big. However, `igraph` does the opposite, and draws lines the thicker the bigger the weight is.

Is there any means to reverse this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to define the width as inversely related to the weight in some way? For instance, using

```
E(g)$width <- 3 - E(g)$weight * 10
```

gives

[image]

You may experiment further and replace 3 and/or 10 with some other coefficients to achieve the desired result.